# Deciding on the name of a class

Tags: design, domain-driven-design, naming

I'm working on a domain where we keep track of food that is stored on various locations, like the fridge or the cellar.

While implementing the domain, I was wondering what the best name would be for the domain class that represents such a *storage location*. Until now, I've used the name `StorageUnit` or `StorageLocation`, but it does not make sense to ask a user what *storage locations* they have around the house.

What would be a better name for this domain object?

Comment: What term are the domain experts using?

Answer (score 4):

If your data processing task involves asking people where they store particular items, then a **Location** is very much part of the domain model.

Many users may use the word "location" very rarely, and it could be a good idea to let your UI talk about "Where do you keep your ..." rather than "Please enter your preferred wine location", but that doesn't mean the *class name* shouldn't be as explicit as possible. If it encodes a location, call it a location already.

(Of course, if you're really distinguishing *properties* of storage, such as "must be accessible within 5 minutes" or "must provide -20°C", rather than concrete locations, then you have an X-Y problem, and you should rethink your class structure.)

Answer (score -2):

You name your class in a way that makes the most sense to you as a software developer. In the UI, if you ask the user where things are stored, you use the words that make most sense to the end user. There is no reason at all why you should use the same name in both cases.

Comment: The question is tagged with domain-driven-design and your suggestion to have a separate model for internal use and communication to the outside is the opposite of the basic principle of DDD